# Differences across borders in table

Tags: tables, beamer

I'm struggling with a very simple table in beamer. The table is the following:

```
\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\Large}c | >{\Large}c  | >{\Large}c  | >{\Large}c } \hline \\ 
    \textbf{Author} & \textbf{Field} & \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Method}  \\ [3ex]  

\hline \hline 
\\ 
M. B\"{o}hme et al. (2018) & Migration & Predict international migration with online search keywords & GTI trends \\  [7ex]

D. Garcia et al. (2018) & Gender inequality & Using Facebook advertising data to infer gender inequality & Fb marketing API \\  [7ex]

L. Timothy et al. (2019) & Health & Is income inequality harmful for health? & Geospatial Big-Data \\  [7ex]

R. Chetty (2020) & Intergenerational mobility & New insights on social mobility in the US & Geospatial information + administrative tax records \\  [7ex]

M. J{\ae}ger \& E.H. Blaab{\ae}k (2020) & Education inequality & Inequality in learning opportunities &  Access and takeout materials from public libraries \\  [7ex]

S. Su at al. (2017) & Health & Socio-economic status and access to healthy food & Geo-big Data on four types of mobility \\  [7ex]

J.L. Toole et al. (2015) & Macro-economics predictions & Unemployment tracking and predictions & Mobile-phone data \\  [7ex]

P. Brown \& M. Souto-Otero (2018) & O-E-D relation & Investigating the E-D relation in UK & Job Adverts from Burning-Glass Labour Insight \\  [7ex]

L Sloan et al. (2015) & Social-class analysis & Obtaining socio-demographic characteristics from Big-Data & Twitter users' description \\ [3ex] 

\hline 

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, I get the following table:
[image]

Why the borders of the columns right to the first one are different and do not close the border?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: there is no need to apply `\Large` to each column it is simpler and will give better spacing to use a single `\Large` before the `tabular`

Comment: your vertical lines are broken as you have `\hline \hline  \\  ` do  not use `\\ ` after `\hline`, you are making an empty row that just has one cell and then ends early so only the first cell has a vertical rule.

Comment: Since you mention `beamer` in your question: I highly doubt this table is ever goint to fit onto a single frame, let alone in a `\large` fonz size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is too big for a4 paper, so the situation is much worse in the `beamer` frame. You need to restrict its width to `\textwidth` and enable to break text in cells into more line. For this is handy to use `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{table}
    \scriptsize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} 
                >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}L
                >{\hsize=0.75\hsize}L
                >{\hsize=1.25\hsize}L
                >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}L @{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Author} & \textbf{Field} & \textbf{Question} & \textbf{Method}  \\
    \midrule
M. B\"{o}hme et al. (2018) & Migration & Predict international migration with online search keywords & GTI trends \\  
    \addlinespace[2pt]
D. Garcia et al. (2018) & Gender inequality & Using Facebook advertising data to infer gender inequality & Fb marketing API \\   
    \addlinespace[2pt]
L. Timothy et al. (2019) & Health & Is income inequality harmful for health? & Geospatial Big-Data \\  
    \addlinespace[2pt]
R. Chetty (2020) & Intergenerational mobility & New insights on social mobility in the US & Geospatial information + administrative tax records \\   
    \addlinespace[2pt]
M. J{\ae}ger \& E.H. Blaab{\ae}k (2020) & Education inequality & Inequality in learning opportunities &  Access and takeout materials from public libraries \\ 
    \addlinespace[2pt]
S. Su at al. (2017) & Health & Socio-economic status and access to healthy food & Geo-big Data on four types of mobility \\  
    \addlinespace[2pt]
J.L. Toole et al. (2015) & Macro-economics predictions & Unemployment tracking and predictions & Mobile-phone data \\  
    \addlinespace[2pt]
P. Brown \& M. Souto-Otero (2018) & O-E-D relation & Investigating the E-D relation in UK & Job Adverts from Burning-Glass Labour Insight \\ 
    \addlinespace[2pt]
L Sloan et al. (2015) & Social-class analysis & Obtaining socio-demographic characteristics from Big-Data & Twitter users' description \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like add to frame a frame title or table caption, you need further reduce table font size or extend table over two slide. For example with use of the `xltabular`, however, its features is not the same as at other documentclases.